# "$(elementId + "_editor") is null" alert box appear while opening wysiwyg editor in magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, wysiwyg

I have a button in magento in add item to open wysiwyg editor.
Once I click on that I got alert box like "$(elementId + "_editor") is null" .
and wysiwyg editor is not opened. Only ok and cancel button of that is opened.

Comment: Did you read this before you post? How can anyone help you with what you provided? You need some more detail, bud.  The most we can possibly do is speculate, "hmm, it looks like something is null".

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to include more detail in the question. Secondly, you need to accept answers to your questions or people will not bother to respond to them. I'm surprised that I'm bothering, but anyway.

From your comment elsewhere, I can see you're saying that the line of code in question is:

```
$(elementId+'_editor').value = $(elementId).value;
```

I have located that line in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/wysiwig/js.phtml`

Line 80, in my version of Magento.

This code works fine as far as I can see. I can't find any google results to indicate people have had the same problem.

You said: "I have a button in magento in add item to open wysiwyg editor."

Does this mean that you have created a button? Are using a custom module? What page does the button appear on?

All of this is information that will be required for people to help you.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add '`#`' in to the selector,

```
$("#" + elementId + "_editor")
```

Comment: $(elementId+'_editor').value = $(elementId).value; This is the line from where null in coming.And it is core file of wysiwyg editor.

Comment: what's the value of elementId?  if elementId is the id of the control, you'll need to prefix '#' to it

Comment: This is incorrect, Magento uses Prototype, not jQuery, so the selector he has there is likely fine.

Comment: Also, the code is core Magento code so it's best he doesn't modify it. He's just tagged the problem incorrectly.